# How to increase speed of Multinomial logistic regression (mnrfit) in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, classification, logistic-regression

I use Multinomial logistic regression (`mnrfit`) command in Matlab to classify a face recognition problem (10 clases).

I use a dimension reduction method to decrease dimension from 2500 to `d`. `d` between `[10 400]`.
`mnrfit` learn model in few seconds when `d` was between `[10 20]` , But when the dimension is greater than 20, learning phase takes a lot of time.

What can I do to increase speed of learning phase for high dimenstion?

Note: I use this command for learning. This command have the good speed

```
[B,dev,stats] = mnrfit(F,Y','model','nominal','interactions','off');
```

but it gives me weak accuracy in comparison to default command

```
[B,dev,stats] = mnrfit(F,Y','interactions','on');
```

I want to do Multinomial logistic regression with good accuracy and high speed in high dimensions, But I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed some parameter and finally find this.

```
[B,dev,stats] = mnrfit(F,Y','model','hierarchical ','interactions','on');
```

this command train model fast and accurate rather than `nominal` model type.